# Minimum percentage of immune when epidemic lowers IQ in the 80's?

Tags: technology, science-fiction, economy, diseases

I have an epidemic of unknown origin spreading across the earth. The effects are decrease in cognitive ability to around [80+ IQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borderline_intellectual_functioning). So we have a surgeons who don't know how to operate, engineers who don't know math, composers who can't read notes, programmers who can't code, writers who could barely read, judges who don't know the law etc.

On average it takes several years for a complete transformation, with large variance between individuals. At first the effect is very slow, but the ability loss accelerates near the end. Since there is no way to test for the epidemic, beside loss of ability everybody is on a edge. Slight fell of performance and people start to believe that you are infected. Since there is no cure, you could easily lose your job and your college degree becomes useless.

What's minimal percentage of a normal population should I keep in order to keep the civilization running?

I want services like water, sewage, electricity, transportation still  running. I want minimum of people who could fix our machines. My aim is to present civilization under severe stress but still barely functioning. Something like a third world country with huge brain drain  [problem](https://ethiopiantimes.wordpress.com/2013/09/24/brain-drain-more-ethiopian-doctors-in-chicago-than-in-ethiopia/)

My aim is something like 10-20% immune, with cutting the rich country services, and retraining remaining humanities, surplus lawyers, bankers, high frequency traders, marketers, non-profit activists, humanities etc.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. To familiarize yourself with this community it's advised to take the [tour] and visit the [help].

Comment: IQ is a measure of deviation from an average. If everybody becomes stupid, stupid becomes the new measure for IQ 100.

Comment: @Renan compared with present

Comment: IQ is not a biological measure, it is largely a test of how close your upbringing is to a middle class white male from an industrialized country.

Comment: @John - Can you back that up with references to meaningful research? I believe that non-white Asians have a mean IQ greater than that of white people, even though the test wasn't designed for their benefit.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Marching_Morons

Comment: http://psycnet.apa.org/doiLanding?doi=10.1037%2F0003-066X.51.2.77 and https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0896627312005843

Comment: @RonJohn 80's IQ is not that low as in your moron story. Those people could do   many jobs that do not require high cognitive load. Construction, crafts, farm-hands, factory workers. Maybe they can't design new car bust they could certainly build one in assembly   line under supervision

Comment: Reducing average IQ to 80+ just means reducing it to the levels of a few decades ago, when there were still surgeons, engineers, composers, writers and judges. IQ has increased significantly over time, and the average IQ in the US in 1932 is estimated to have been 80 by the standards of 1997. It’s called the Flynn Effect. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flynn_effect

Comment: I think the surgeons will be fine.

Comment: Does minority rule in style of South Africa before '89 counts as "keep the civilization running"?

Comment: I'm not sure anyone has correctly identified what IQ actually is. It's probably worth viewing the whole of this video which explains how it is calculated and its history, including its use by the army in the US and by socialists in Britain wanting to raise opportunities for the less advantaged classes . https://youtu.be/fsZK4yvKt-o?t=35

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IQ is not as simple as you may think. There are many different types of intelligence, including logistic, spatial, musical, interpersonal, intrapersonal, and naturalist, to name a few. Most IQ tests, which are used to produce the famed "IQ Level", only tackle logistic and spatial intelligence, without crediting a person's other mental abilities.

So, essentially, what your virus does is simply limit a person's ability to perform calculations, form hypotheses, and visualize the world around them. While this will affect everyone significantly, most jobs do not rely on those skills whatsoever, with interpersonal, linguistic, naturalist, and bodily-kinesthetic being far more important intelligences to have in most people's careers. Only highly technical positions, such as scientists and engineers, will be impacted heavily by this virus. Heck, the virus won't even remove a person's ability to read, which is the most valued skill in any job hands down.

So while your virus may inhibit research, invention, and technological progress in general, a majority of the population will continue to move on as usual, without losing their livelihoods or anything drastic like that.

Comment: McNamara shared your belief. He even tried his luck in conscripting low IQ individuals in to army with slightly more training. Let's say it turned out that in army actually thinking even among low ranks was necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Although it varies widely depending on the profession we are talking about and the country, and you also have people with abilities unemployed, things are barely working as they are. You don't have enough professionals for everyone in the world as it is. I'd guess you need 85/90 of people immune.
On the other hand, knowing of the problem, efforts would be made to qualify enough people to replace the ones that retire over time. Professionals would have to work overtime as teachers and they would be supervised in case they are infected, but they could maintain the balance. With that system in place you could lower the critical percentage a a bit.

Comment: Whilst I see what you're getting at, what a contemporary economy considers 'enough' is never met, it can never be because of economic principles that are established and maintained as a result of existing conditions(assumptions of finite supply, expectations of relative wealth etc.) Agriculture and essential services utilize a fraction of the total number of people they once did to provide for multiples of the total people they once did... yet 'we don't have enough people or we don't have enough jobs' etc. Minimum limits of functionality are a part of the question.